# Issue with legend pagination (Google Interactive chart API)

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

I am using google interactive chart for showing chart like linechart, 
barchart, piechart etc. 
I am showing legends in the top of chart. For long legends, the 
legends are appearing in terms of pagination after new release of Google Visualization API(7th 
November 2010) by default. 
But i don't want to show this as pagination. Can it possible to show 
this in different way by that all legends come under one view in top? 
Or can it possible to show the more legends in the second line i.e 
just below of 1st line of legends(in case of more)? 
I am not able to find how to configure this. 
Please help me. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Once can specify the font size of the legend:

```
legendTextStyle: {color: <string>, fontName: <string>, fontSize: <number>}
```

or alternatively play around with the width of the chart to make up more room for the legend.

See more: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart.html