# Google Charts legends overlapping

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am new to Stackoverflow and google charts.

I am facing a problem in one of my project which uses google charts api, I am drawing two legends but they are overlapping on preview.

I tried various solution on stackoverflow and jsfiddle but none of them worked.

Here are some of my code snippet and output:

**Configuration Object for Chart :**

```
    var options = {
        hAxis : {
            title : xAxis,
            textStyle:{
                color: 'black',
                fontSize : '8px'
            },
            slantedText : true,
            slantedTextAngle : 90,
            titleTextStyle : {
                fontSize : '15px',
                italic : false
            },
        },
        vAxis : {
            title : yAxis,
            format:format,
            textStyle:{
                color: 'black',
                fontSize : '8px'
            },
            titleTextStyle : {
                fontSize : '15px',
                italic : false
            },
            viewWindowMode : 'explicit',
            viewWindow : {
                min : 0,
                //max: 1200000
            }
        },
        backgroundColor : 'transparent',
        interpolateNulls: false,
        width : 350,
        height : 180,
        chartArea : {
            left : 40,
            width : '45%',
            height : '45%'
        },
     legend: {
          position: 'top',
            maxLines: 3,
        },
        series : {
            0 : {
                color : line1Color,
                visibleInLegend : true,
                pointShape: 'square',
                pointSize: 10,
            },
            1 : {
                color : line2Color,
                visibleInLegend : true,
                pointShape: 'diamond',
                pointSize: 10,
            }
        }
    };
```

**Output:**
https://snag.gy/Yd2qjX.jpg

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there isn't an option for forcing multiple lines on the legend

I could never get the legends to overlap as in the screen shot,
instead each would be cutoff, with *'...'* at the end

but the only way I could get the legend text to drop to another line and not cutoff,
was by increasing the `width` by a rediculous amout
needed to adjust `chartArea.width` as well

so you might be able to continue to adjust both `width` and `chartArea.width`,
until you get the desired result

one other note, anytime you use `fontSize` in the chart `options`,
it should be a number, instead of a string, i.e.
`fontSize : 8`

vs.

`fontSize : '8px'`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Tool - Long title could not read', 'Tool - Something to Prod Start'],
      [new Date('08/01/2015'), 0.2, 0.0],
      [new Date('09/01/2015'), 0.8, 0.0],
      [new Date('10/01/2015'), 1.0, 2.2],
      [new Date('11/01/2015'), 1.3, 1.2],
      [new Date('12/01/2015'), 1.8, 1.4],
      [new Date('01/01/2016'), 2.4, 1.5],
      [new Date('02/01/2016'), 2.5, 1.4],
      [new Date('03/01/2016'), 2.6, 1.5],
      [new Date('04/01/2016'), 2.5, 1.5],
      [new Date('05/01/2016'), 2.4, 1.6],
      [new Date('06/01/2016'), 2.3, 1.6],
      [new Date('07/01/2016'), 2.2, 1.5]
    ]);

    var options = {
        hAxis : {
            title : 'xAxis',
            format: 'MMM-yy',
            textStyle:{
                color: 'black',
                fontSize : 8
            },
            slantedText : true,
            slantedTextAngle : 90,
            titleTextStyle : {
                fontSize : 15,
                italic : false
            },
        },
        vAxis : {
            title : 'yAxis',
            format: '#,##0.0',
            textStyle:{
                color: 'black',
                fontSize : 8
            },
            titleTextStyle : {
                fontSize : 15,
                italic : false
            },
            viewWindowMode : 'explicit',
            viewWindow : {
                min : 0
            }
        },
        backgroundColor : 'transparent',
        interpolateNulls: false,
        width : 780,
        height : 180,
        chartArea : {
            left : 40,
            width : 310,
            height : '45%'
        },
        legend: {
            position: 'top',
            maxLines: 3
        },
        series : {
            0 : {
                color : '#154360',
                visibleInLegend : true,
                pointShape: 'square',
                pointSize: 10,
            },
            1 : {
                color : '#5499C7',
                visibleInLegend : true,
                pointShape: 'diamond',
                pointSize: 10,
            }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer but it didn't work for me. I tried to set both the width and font size but it still overlapping. May be it's the internal CSS issue.

Comment: it took several tries to get the above to work, it may be worth building your own legend in an adjacent `div` -- [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36064828/5090771)

Comment: Yes, Thanks I got it