# Zero value in google pie charts

Tags: angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am using angularjs and Google charts.

How to include zero values in Google Pie Chart? I am able to show it in the legend by including ***sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0***
[see screenshot to see what I already have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MwP8.png)

But what I want is to display it in both legend and in the chart: [display zero value in pie chart like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR8hR.png)

Is there any way to achieve what I want? I searched in Google forums but couldn't find any solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use the option for `legend.position: 'labeled'` to show a line for the zero values

```
  legend: {
    position: 'labeled'
  },
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      "cols": [
        {"label": "Country", "type": "string"},
        {"label": "# of Devices", "type": "number"}
      ],
      "rows": [
        {"c": [{"v": "Canada"}, {"v": 0}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "Mexico"}, {"v": 33}]},
        {"c": [{"v": "USA"}, {"v": 34}]}
      ]
    });

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);

    chart.draw(data, {
      height: 400,
      legend: {
        position: 'labeled'
      },
      sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
      width: 600
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I also want to display Legend at the bottom (along with the pie slice values). So I don't think I can use this method!

Comment: you could add your own custom legend -- [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36064828/5090771)