# google chart legend in mobile reponsive

Tags: html, charts, google-visualization

in google chart legend lable in mobile responsive legend is slider  ,I need to not silder legend but legend wordwrap.

[image]

```
      var options = {
            legend: {position:"bottom" , alignment: 'top'},
          vAxis: {
                viewWindowMode:'explicit',
            viewWindow: {
                max:<?=$target?>,
                min:0
            }
          },
          seriesType: 'bars',
          series: {3: {type: 'area'}},
          colors: ['CornflowerBlue', 'green', 'red', '#0099c6']
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

only available option is `legend.maxLines`...

> Set this to a number greater than one to add lines to your legend. Note: this option currently works only when `legend.position` is `'top'`.

with...

`legend.position: 'top'`

Comment: or you could just [build your own legend](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36064828/5090771)...