# Create a legend for stack graph having different color for each series

Tags: charts, salesforce, visualforce

Hi I have created stack column chart and it has two series :RTM and ITM. As per the requirement RTM has same color for each bar but ITM has different color for each bar. I have done this using role --> style.
Now, I want to show the color in legends as per the series but it seems that it would not be possible.
Any help would be really appreciable.
Please find below expected legend format
RTM ->it's color
ITM
ITM.first bar...>it's color
ITM.second bar...>it's color so on....

Comment: sounds like you're using google charts? if so, colors set with the style role will not sync with the legend -- one option would be put each ITM value into a separate column, which would create a series for each and a separate color -- another option would be to hide the standard legend and implement a custom one in an adjacent container, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064828/5090771)...

Comment: I was trying to use first option but ITM values are not static, they can be increased when values are added into system. ---- i will try to use another option and let u know if have any issue.... Thanks!!