# Chart.js Multiple charts with one common legend

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

There are multiple charts on one page.
Each chart line is common.
I want to display a legend that is common to multiple charts like the figure.It shows and hides all chart lines with OnClick like the default legend.
[image: THIS PICT IS FAKE]
***THIS PICT IS FAKE***

Is that possible? how?

I had tried [Chart.js sync legend toggle on multiple charts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51920455/10940818), [One legend, multiple charts Chart JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51610867/10940818) and etc.
But, those solutions have one chart with legend, and that legend affects other charts.

Should I hide the chart and show only the legend?
Should I draw a chart with no data?

I would be grad if you could tell me

HTML

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/nnnick/Chart.js/v1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.0.0-beta/Chart.js"></script>
<div>
    <canvas id="myChartA"></canvas>
</div>

<div>
    <canvas id="myChartB"></canvas>
</div>
```

JS

```
var ctxA = document.getElementById("myChartA").getContext("2d");
var ctxB = document.getElementById("myChartB").getContext("2d");

let data_A1 = [{
        x: "2019-01-01 00:01:38",
        y: "13.0"
    },
    {
        x: "2019-01-01 01:01:39",
        y: "11.0"
    },
    {
        x: "2019-01-01 02:01:40",
        y: "16.0"
    },
    {
        x: "2019-01-01 03:01:41",
        y: "15.0"
    },
    {
        x: "2019-01-01 04:01:42",
        y: "14.0"
    }
];

var data_A2 = [{
    x: "2019-01-01 00:01:42",
    y: 14.671
}, {
    x: "2019-01-01 01:01:42",
    y: 13.691
}, {
    x: "2019-01-01 02:01:42",
    y: 16.691
}, {
    x: "2019-01-01 03:01:42",
    y: 17.691
}, {
    x: "2019-01-01 04:01:42",
    y: 18.691
}];

let data_B1 = [{
        x: "2019-01-02 00:01:38",
        y: "12.0"
    },
    {
        x: "2019-01-02 01:01:39",
        y: "11.0"
    },
    {
        x: "2019-01-02 02:01:40",
        y: "13.0"
    },
    {
        x: "2019-01-02 03:01:41",
        y: "14.0"
    },
    {
        x: "2019-01-02 04:01:42",
        y: "16.0"
    }
];

var data_B2 = [{
    x: "2019-01-02 00:00:00",
    y: 14.671
}, {
    x: "2019-01-02 01:01:42",
    y: 13.691
}, {
    x: "2019-01-02 02:01:42",
    y: 16.691
}, {
    x: "2019-01-02 03:01:42",
    y: 15.691
}, {
    x: "2019-01-02 04:01:42",
    y: 14.691
}];


var myChartA = new Chart(ctxA, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: '1st Data',
            data: data_A1,
            borderColor: '#0f0',
            showLine: true
        }, {
            label: '2nd Data',
            data: data_A2,
            borderColor: '#f00',
            showLine: true
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormat: 'h:mm',
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});

var myChartB = new Chart(ctxB, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: '1st Data',
            data: data_B1,
            borderColor: '#0f0',
            showLine: true
        }, {
            label: '2nd Data',
            data: data_B2,
            borderColor: '#f00',
            showLine: true
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    displayFormat: 'h:mm',
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using the beta version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a common legend and through generateLegend api, if both the datasets are similar.

First disable the default legends though the options

```
legend: {
        display: false
      }
```

Then use generateLegend() api to get the data labels and set it to a common element.

```
<ul class="legend">

</ul>
```

Then add event listeners to the generated elements and target all the charts

```
document.querySelector('.legend').innerHTML = myChartA.generateLegend();

var legendItems = document.querySelector('.legend').getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < legendItems.length; i++) {
  legendItems[i].addEventListener("click", legendClickCallback.bind(this,i), false);
}

function legendClickCallback(legendItemIndex){
  document.querySelectorAll('.myChart').forEach((chartItem,index)=>{
    var chart = Chart.instances[index];
    var dataItem = chart.data.datasets[legendItemIndex]    
    if(dataItem.hidden == true || dataItem.hidden == null){
      dataItem.hidden = false;
    } else {
      dataItem.hidden = true;
    }
    chart.update();
  })  
}
```

A sample pen is present here
https://codepen.io/srajagop/pen/yLBJOOo

Note I am using chartjs 2.8

Comment: is there a way to get the color and use the same style from chartjs?

Comment: @karthick generateLegend() function has been deprecated im chartjs v3.x, how can we do this in chartjs v3?

Comment: is there a way to do this on chartjs 3.0+?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone using React version of Chartjs particularly react-chartjs-2, I have done it using React Hooks with react-chartjs-2, see the sandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-resonance-ef5o6)