# How to display only one label in a multi line char?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I create a diagram with chart.js. This diagram has two lines. So it displays also two labels by default. But I need a configuration where one for example the red label should appear and the blue one should be hidden. The label **not** the line!!

Thanks for your help

```js
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['16:30', '17:30', '18:30', '19:30', '20:30'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'High',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      data: [10.43, 10.42, 10.44, 10.43, 10.40],
      fill: false,
    }, {
      label: 'low',
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      data: [8.43, 8.5, 8.39, 8.38, 8.38],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Test'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Time'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Value'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
};
var ctx = $('#dia');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>


<canvas id="dia"></canvas>
```

Comment: Is it the legend you are referring to or the tooltips on the lines when you hover.. If legend then refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528694/chart-js-multiple-charts-with-one-common-legend

Comment: I'm referring to the legend. The example in your link does not show both values.

Comment: @InFlames82: So, for example, should the legend only contain "Heigh" and hide only the "Heigh" line when you click on it? Shall it not be possible at all to hide the "low" line?

Comment: No, it shall not be possible to hide the 'low' line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`legend.labels.generateLabels`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html?h=generatelabel#legend-label-configuration) together with [`legend.onClick`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html?h=generatelabel#custom-on-click-actions) action to achieve this.

```js
var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: ['16:30', '17:30', '18:30', '19:30', '20:30'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'High',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            borderColor: 'blue',
            data: [10.43, 10.42, 10.44, 10.43, 10.40],
            fill: false,
        }, {
            label: 'low',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            borderColor: 'red',
            data: [8.43, 8.5, 8.39, 8.38, 8.38],
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Test'
        },
        legend: {
            labels: {
                generateLabels: chart => {
                    let dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
                    return [{                        
                        chart: chart,
                        text: dataset.label,
                        fillStyle: dataset.backgroundColor,
                        strokeStyle: dataset.borderColor,
                        hidden: chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden
                    }]
                }
            },
            onClick: (mouseEvent, legendItem) => {
              legendItem.chart.getDatasetMeta(0).hidden = !legendItem.hidden;
              legendItem.chart.update();
            }
        },
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false,
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'nearest',
            intersect: true
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Time'
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Value'
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
var ctx = $('#dia');
new Chart(ctx, config);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="dia"></canvas>
```