# How can I hide legend text if it's zero?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm trying to hide the legend title of an item, if it's value is zero. There are similar problems existing here, but nothing led to solving my problem.

Below is my source code:

```
<script>
      var ctx = document.getElementById('beratungsfelderChart');
      var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C', 'Group D', 'Group E'],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [0, 3, 3, 5, 2],
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#172b4dD9',
                    '#2dce89D9',
                    '#231F20D9',
                    '#192d35D9',
                    '#3B6058D9'
                ]
            }]
        },
        options: {
          legend: {
            labels: {
              //filter: function(item, chart, context) {
              //  return !item.text.includes('Test');
              //}
              filter: function(item, context) {
                return !context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] == 0;
              } 
            }
          },
          axis: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    display: false
                }],
                xAes: [{
                  ticks: {
                    display: false
                  }
                }]
            }
          },
          plugins: {
            datalabels: {
              display: function(context) {
                return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] > 1;
              }
            }
          }
        }
    });

    </script>
```

As you can see I tried a few potential solutions, but until now, nothing worked out unfortunately.
1. options -> legend -> labels 
2. options -> plugins -> datalabels

I hope that someone can help me somehow.

Best,
Nader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`legend.labels.filter`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#configuration-options) as follows.

```
legend: {
  labels: {
    filter: (legendItem, data) => data.datasets[0].data[legendItem.index] != 0
  }
}
```

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('beratungsfelderChart'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C', 'Group D', 'Group E'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [0, 3, 3, 5, 2],
      backgroundColor: [
        '#172b4dD9',
        '#2dce89D9',
        '#231F20D9',
        '#192d35D9',
        '#3B6058D9'
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        filter: (legendItem, data) => data.datasets[0].data[legendItem.index] != 0
      }
    },
    axis: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          display: false
        }],
        xAes: [{
          ticks: {
            display: false
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script> 
<canvas id="beratungsfelderChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you so much! :)
Btw.. Do you know how to deactivate cross out a legenditem, when its value is 0? :P

Comment: @Nad3rk93: You need to implement `legend.generateLabels` function, similar as explained in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60000077/2358409

Comment: The option seems to be located on [`options.plugins.legend.labels.filter`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.4.1/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) now

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY is right. The updated code is as follows: `options: { plugins: { legend: { labels: { filter: (legendItem, data) => data.datasets[0].data[legendItem.index] != 0 } } } }`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `generateLabels` instead of filter. it's a newer method and you would be able to change value and style of each legends. For example I've removed zero values and added data to each label :

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('beratungsfelderChart'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C', 'Group D', 'Group E'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [0, 3, 3, 5, 2],
      backgroundColor: [
        '#192d35',
        '#36A2EB',
        '#FFCE56',
        '#FF6384',
        '#3B6058'
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
          generateLabels: function (chart) {
                var newLegends = [];
                chart.data.labels.forEach(function (label, index) {
                    if (chart.data.datasets[0].data[index] == 0) //zero values
                        return;
                    var legend = {
                        text: label + ' ('+chart.data.datasets[0].data[index]+')',
                        fillStyle: chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor[index]
                    };
                    newLegends.push(legend)
                });

                return newLegends;
            }
      }
    },
    axis: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          display: false
        }],
        xAes: [{
          ticks: {
            display: false
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script> 
<canvas id="beratungsfelderChart" height="90"></canvas>
```