# Angular Chart.js get clicked legend value

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, legend, marker

I have multiple **Ng2** line charts and want to solve that problem that if I click onto a legend marker on a chart then it should be clicked onto the other charts too.

Picture about the problem :

[image]

I could not find any solution so far.

Comment: Let me see if I understood it right. You want to replicate a click in a chart's legend to all other charts containing the same data, right?

Comment: Duplicate for V2: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57528694/8682983