# How to show legend for the Timeline Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I am working on the reports using Timeline Google Chart. Now, I want a legend for the same chart. Can we have a legend for a Timeline google chart? If yes, how to implement that? Well, I have gone through the documentation of Google chart, the examples(for legend) given were for the other charts(Bar, Line) but not for the Timeline chart.
   Your response will highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: the timeline chart does not have a legend...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat for your response. As Timeline chart doesn't have a legend, is there any solution to do that? Bar label could be a solution but the problem is when chart rendered bar label appears outside of the bar if bar size is small (This problem limited for first and last bar only).

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064828/5090771) shows how to create a custom legend for a normal chart, you possible adapt to the timeline