# Angular Google Charts: how to set different colors to columns in column chart

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

I am using Angular 9 + Google Charts via npm: npm install angular-google-charts

I want to set different colors to all columns in column charts but it's setting first color to all columns.

Did anybody encounter such problem or have any solution for setting different colors to columns in google column chart?

HTML:

```
<google-chart #chart
   [title]="title"
   [type]="type"
   [data]="data"
   [columns]="columnNames"
   [options]="options"
   [width]="width"
   [height]="height">
</google-chart>
```

TypeScript:

```
export class ColumnChartComponent[![enter image description here][1]][1] {
  title = 'Population (in millions)';
  type = 'ColumnChart';
  data = [
     ["2012", 900],
     ["2013", 1000],
     ["2014", 1170],
     ["2015", 1250],
     ["2016", 1530]
  ];
  columnNames = ['Year', 'Asia'];

  // chart options in which I am setting colors
  options = {
    colors: ['#5cb85c', '#f0ad4e', '#d9534f', '#5bc0de', '#f6c7b6'],
  };

  width = 550;
  height = 400;
}
```

[image: Google Column Chart]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, As there isn't a straight forward solution available get the different colors for all columns in angular-google-column-chart with nice colored legends.
I came up with a trick cum workaround to get the desired result using stacked column chart to achive this.

TypeScript:

```
title = 'Resources Status Overview';
  type = 'ColumnChart';

// => here is the trick. set single colored value for the column and rest to 0.
  data = [
    ["Ready", 500, 0, 0, 0],
    ["Pending", 0, 360, 0, 0],
    ["Deployed", 0, 0, 410, 0],
    ["Other", 0, 0, 0, 200],
  ];

  columnNames = ['Status', 'Ready', 'Pending', 'Deployed', 'Other'];

  options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Status'
    },
    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0
    },
    isStacked: true,
    colors: ['#5cb85c', '#f0ad4e', '#d9534f', '#5bc0de']
  };

  width = 600;
  height = 400;
```

It's a trick with the data set. In the stacked columns, set rest of the colors to 0 and keep the value in only for the matching color and you will get the nice column chart with legends.
If you have limited data then this would be a nice solution for you.

[image: Column Chart with colors]

Comment: thanks :) yeah, wanted to do it as posted. but it was saying wait for a day to accept it as an answer.

Comment: @JagdishChopde I have the same Problem but this solution would not work for me. I have a Timeline and want to have different colors. Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: @MatthiasNeubert Can you please explain what do you mean by Timeline? Are you referring a another type of graph?

Answer (score 2):

each entry in the `colors` array, applies to each series in the data table.
the data table in the example only has one series, or y-axis column.

```
data = [
   ["2012", 900],
   ["2013", 1000],
   ["2014", 1170],
   ["2015", 1250],
   ["2016", 1530]
];
columnNames = ['Year', 'Asia'];
```

in order to have a different color for each bar using the `colors` option,
each value needs to be in a different data table column.

e.g.

```
data = [
   ['Asia', 900, 1000, 1170, 1250, 1530]
];
columnNames = ['Country', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'];
```

---

another option is to use a style column role.
this option allows you to add the color to the data table,
and color each bar individually, without having multiple series.

```
data = [
   ["2012", 900, '#5cb85c'],
   ["2013", 1000, '#f0ad4e'],
   ["2014", 1170, '#d9534f'],
   ["2015", 1250, '#5bc0de'],
   ["2016", 1530, '#f6c7b6']
];
columnNames = ['Year', 'Asia', {role: 'style', type: 'string'}];
```

the only drawback to using the style role,
the legend will not match the colors.
it uses the same approach as the `colors` option,
and will only display the one series,
using the first color in the `colors` option.

Comment: In the first option, the colors are coming with legends but as those data is part of one series all columns are coming as sticking to each other as one group. In second option, the legends are not coming as you mentioned already as a drawback.

Comment: you might try the `bar.groupWidth` config option for the first scenario, but not sure if it will work. you could try creating your own legend for the second scenario, [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064828/5090771)...