# Google React Charts Placement & Legend Placement

Tags: reactjs, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I am having troubles placing the google react charts on the left of a full width container without the legend thinking it's being cut off.

If I leave it as a default it looks like this:

[image]

However I want it to be on the left side and the legend to be next to it.

When I change the position of the chart area:

```
chartArea: {
            left: 0,
            right: 400,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            width: '100%',
            height: '80%',
        },
```

It then looks like this:

[image]

For whatever reason it thinks there isn't enough space and it cuts the legend text which is really annoying.

Here is the code I am using:

```
const pieOptions = {
        title: '',
        pieHole: 0.6,
        slices: [
            {
                color: '#00A3E0',
            },
            {
                color: '#F2A900',
            },
            {
                color: '#43B02A',
            },
            {
                color: '#DF4661',
            },
            {
                color: '#003865',
            },
            {
                color: '#A15A95',
            },
            {
                color: '#FF6A13',
            },
        ],
        legend: {
            position: 'right',
            alignment: 'end',
            textStyle: {
                color: '#666',
                fontSize: 12,
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
            showColorCode: true,
        },
        chartArea: {
            left: 0,
            right: 400,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            width: '100%',
            height: '80%',
        },
        fontName: 'inherit',
        fontSize: 12,
    }
```

Can anyone advise?

Also if this is not fixable, can you please recommend a chart which supports that and custom colours please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: google's pie chart is the worst for trying to size properly. the biggest problem is that the "chart area" includes the legend. so there is not a way to size the chart itself, independently of the legend. I think you might have better luck removing the legend, and creating your own custom legend. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064828/5090771) is an example...