# How to display total count of bars for each group in Google Charts on the right side of the graph or in legend position

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, google-visualization

I'm currently working on a grouped bar chart using Google Charts, and I've encountered an issue with the legend display. In the current configuration, the legend on the right side of the graph displays individual bar values for both "interface" and "functional" groups. However, I would like to modify it to display the total count of bars for each group instead.

In summary, instead of showing individual "NASC" and "FASC" values in the legend on the right side of the graph, I want it to display the total count of bars for the "interface" and "functional" groups separately. What modifications do I need to make to achieve this?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
Here's the relevant part of the code I'm working with:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Grouped Bar Chart Example</title>
    <!-- Load Google Charts library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawBarGroupChart(containerId, chartData, title, defect) {
            // Convert javaData object into an array of arrays
            var data = [];
            var types = Object.keys(chartData);
            var defects = {};
            var jiraData = chartData;

            // Collect all unique defect keys
            types.forEach(function (type) {
                Object.assign(defects, chartData[type]);
            });

            // Create the header row
            var headerRow = ['Type'];
            Object.keys(defects).forEach(function (defect) {
                headerRow.push(defect);
            });
            data.push(headerRow);

            // Populate data rows
            types.forEach(function (type) {
                var row = [type];
                Object.keys(defects).forEach(function (defect) {
                    row.push(chartData[type][defect] || 0);
                });
                data.push(row);
            });

            var chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

            var options = {
                title: 'Total Days to resolve defect',
                vAxis: { title: 'Days' },
                hAxis: { title: 'Type' },
                seriesType: 'bars',
                series: {}
            };

            var index = 0;
            defect.forEach(function (defect) {
                var groupSize = Object.keys(jiraData[defect.defectType]).length;
                for (var i = 0; i < groupSize; i++) {
                    options.series[index++] = { color: defect.color };
                }
            });

            // Set the width of the bars
            options.bar = { groupWidth: '100%' };  // Adjust the width as needed
            
            

            var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById(containerId));
            chart.draw(chartData, options);
        }

        function drawChart() {
            // Sample data for chartData
            var chartData = {
                'interface': {
                    'NASC-1': 1,
                    'NASC-2': 2,
                    'NASC-3': 1,
                    'NASC-4': 2,
                    'NASC-5': 1,
                    'NASC-6': 2,
                    'NASC-7': 1,
                    'NASC-8': 2,
                    'NASC-9': 1,
                    'NASC-10': 2,
                    'NASC-13': 1,
                    'NASC-14': 2,
                    'NASC-15': 1,
                    'NASC-16': 2,
                    'NASC-17': 1,
                    'NASC-18': 2,
                    'NASC-26': 2,
                    'NASC-27': 1,
                    'NASC-28': 2,
                    'NASC-29': 1,
                    'NASC-20': 2,
                    'NASC-23': 1,
                    'NASC-124': 2,
                    'NASC-25': 1,
                    'NASC-26': 2,
                    'NASC-27': 1,
                    'NASC-28': 2
                },
                'functional': {
                    'FASC-1': 1,
                    'FASC-2': 2,
                    'FASC-3': 1
                }
            };

            // Sample data for defect
            var defect = [
                { defectType: 'functional', color: 'grey' },
                { defectType: 'interface', color: 'orange' }
            ];

            drawBarGroupChart('chart_div', chartData, 'Total Days to resolve defect', defect);
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Add Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Bootstrap container -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- Chart container -->
                <div id="chart_div" style="height: 500px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <!-- Additional content in the second column -->
                <p>Additional content in the second column</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Load Google Charts library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <!-- Load Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Current Status
[image]

Desired Result
[image]

Comment: there are no configuration options that will display the count in the legend. you could get it down to two legend items (without counts) by re-configuring the data table, but that would also change the format of the chart. only other option is to build a custom legend, and choose not to display the chart's legend. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36064828/5090771) is a general example...